# sed find replace string with special characters

Tags: sed, latex, special-characters, replace

I am trying to use sed to find/replace a string with special characters in a text file. I'm attempting to use a command like this:

```
sed -i -e 's/one\_test/FIRST TEST/g' tables.tex
```

So, replace 'one_test' with 'FIRST TEST' in tables.tex

This command doesn't work, I think because of the \ character. Does anybody know what I can do to get this working?

Comment: try using sed -i -e 's/one\\_test/TEST/g' tables.tex

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: `_` is not a special character, so why not use:
`'s/one_test/FIRST TEST/g'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/one\\_test/TEST/g' tables.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case... if this may help

I have a string like onstar. i need to replace it with onstar_system.

i did this,

sed -i 's/onstar\./onstar_system\./g' filename

this worked for me.